# Android Studio 3.0 after rebuilding Duplicate zip entry warnings

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

After rebuiding my Java/Kotlin project I have got lot of warnings in Gradle console. How can I remove the warnings?

[image]
I try packagingOptions in my build.gradle:

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
   apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
   apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.eusecom.samfantozzi"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

packagingOptions {

    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
    //duplicate files copied in apk meta-inf/rxjava
    exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
    exclude 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
    exclude '1.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
}

}

dependencies {
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestImplementation ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'

debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5.1'
releaseImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5.1'
testImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5.1'


def daggerVer = 2.11

implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$daggerVer"
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$daggerVer"
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$daggerVer"
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVer"

//kotlin drawer
implementation 'co.zsmb:materialdrawer-kt:1.1.1'
//anko dsl
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-common:$anko_version"
compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-sdk15:$anko_version"
compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-appcompat-v7:$anko_version"
compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-design:$anko_version"
compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-recyclerview-v7:$anko_version"


//Firebase
//Firebase Authentication email password
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.0'
//Firebase database
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.0'

//picasso
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'

//retrofit2
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'

//rxjava
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.1'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
implementation 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.0'

// libs like rxbinding + rxjava-math haven't been ported to RxJava 2.x yet, so this helps
implementation "com.github.akarnokd:rxjava2-interop:0.6.1"
implementation 'io.reactivex:rxjava-math:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxrelay2:rxrelay:2.0.0'
implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding:0.2.0'
implementation 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'


}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

In my project/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.3-2'
ext.anko_version = '0.8.2'
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha7'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}
```

Comment: I have got warnings by building for API 18 device. If I build with API 24 device  the warnings do not get.